# Read variable from project for Octopus Deploy step

Tags: octopus-deploy

I have an Octopus Deploy project that successfully deploys a package as a Windows service on the target machine.  Prior to deploying the actual service I have a couple of steps that ensure that the targeted account is (for example) allowed to listen on the appropriate port.

At the moment, I have information (like port number) hard-coded into the scripts for the deployment steps.  I know how to use variables to avoid the hard-coding.  However, some of the variables really "belong" in the service itself rather than in the deployment project.

Is there any way in which I can read information from the package under deployment and use that information as a variable in Octopus Deploy steps prior to the actual package deployment?

Answer (score 2):

One way (not very elegant though) to achieve what you want i think would be to use [Output Variables](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/variables/output-variables). Here's also nice [blog post](https://octopus.com/blog/fun-with-output-variables) about this from Octopus.

So the idea is that you could have dedicated PS script in your package which would set Octopus output variables for port numbers, e. g.

```
Set-OctopusVariable -name "PortNumber" -value "8080"
```

You could run this script with basic "Run a Script" step (e.g. named "SetVariables") which you can configure running script from a package:

[image]
And in further deploy process you can retrieve this variable from any step using Octopus variable binding syntax:

```
#{Octopus.Action[SetVariables].Output.PortNumber}
```

or PS syntax:

```
$portNumber = $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Action[SetVariables].Output.PortNumber"]
```

The thing why i don't really like this approach is because it significantly complicates deploy process and adds additional dependencies *from setter script to Octopus* and from *variable reading script / usage place to step name*.

I would probably stick to more robust ways to scope the parameters like config transformations, or just scoping to broader area like target machine. If that's possible obviously.